# Is this a Chrome issue at rendering CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This is how Chrome render [this page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Discussione_tra_due_ragazze_per_i_botti_e_gli_animali):

The font size is set to 100% in the whole table.

[image]

And here the render in Firefox Developer Edition

[image]

```css
.client-nojs #ca-ve-edit,.client-nojs .mw-editsection-divider,.client-nojs .mw-editsection-visualeditor,.ve-not-available #ca-ve-edit,.ve-not-available .mw-editsection-divider,.ve-not-available .mw-editsection-visualeditor {
    display: none
}

.client-js .mw-content-ltr .mw-editsection-bracket:first-of-type,.client-js .mw-content-rtl .mw-editsection-bracket:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    color: #54595d
}

.client-js .mw-content-rtl .mw-editsection-bracket:first-of-type,.client-js .mw-content-ltr .mw-editsection-bracket:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    color: #54595d
}

body {
    margin: 0
}

main {
    display: block
}

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible
}

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    cursor: help
}

@supports (text-decoration: underline dotted) {
    abbr[title] {
        border-bottom:0;
        text-decoration: underline dotted
    }
}

pre,code,tt,kbd,samp {
    font-family: monospace,monospace
}

sub,sup {
    line-height: 1
}

img {
    border: 0
}

button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {
    margin: 0
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,[type='button']::-moz-focus-inner,[type='reset']::-moz-focus-inner,[type='submit']::-moz-focus-inner {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0
}

legend {
    color: inherit;
    padding: 0
}

.messagebox,.errorbox,.warningbox,.successbox {
    color: #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden
}

.messagebox :only-child,.errorbox :only-child,.warningbox :only-child,.successbox :only-child {
    margin: 0
}

.messagebox h2,.errorbox h2,.warningbox h2,.successbox h2 {
    color: inherit;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold
}

.messagebox .mw-logevent-loglines li,.errorbox .mw-logevent-loglines li,.warningbox .mw-logevent-loglines li,.successbox .mw-logevent-loglines li {
    font-size: 90%
}

.messagebox {
    background-color: #eaecf0;
    border-color: #a2a9b1
}

.errorbox {
    background-color: #fee7e6;
    border-color: #d33
}

.warningbox {
    background-color: #fef6e7;
    border-color: #fc3
}

.successbox {
    background-color: #d5fdf4;
    border-color: #14866d
}

.toctogglecheckbox:checked ~ ul {
    display: none
}

@media screen {
    html,body {
        height: 100%
    }

    :focus {
        outline-color: #3366cc
    }

    body {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        overflow-y: scroll
    }

    .mw-body,.parsoid-body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #202122;
        direction: ltr;
        padding: 1em
    }

    #p-personal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        right: 0.75em;
        z-index: 100
    }

    #p-personal ul {
        padding-left: 10em
    }

    #p-personal li {
        float: left
    }

    .mw-body,#mw-data-after-content {
        margin-left: 10em
    }

    .mw-body {
        margin-top: -1px;
        border: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
        border-right-width: 0
    }

    .mw-body .firstHeading {
        overflow: visible
    }

    .mw-indicators {
        z-index: 1
    }

    .mw-body-content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0
    }

    #bodyContent:after {
        clear: both;
        content: '';
        display: block
    }

    .mw-parser-output:after {
        content: none
    }

    #mw-page-base {
        background-color: #fbfbfb;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffffff 50%,#f6f6f6 100%);
        background-position: bottom left;
        height: 5em
    }

    #mw-head-base {
        margin-top: -5em;
        margin-left: 10em;
        height: 5em
    }

    #mw-navigation h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px
    }

    #mw-head {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%
    }

    #left-navigation {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10em;
        margin-top: 2.5em;
        margin-bottom: -2.5em
    }

    #right-navigation {
        float: right;
        margin-top: 2.5em
    }

    #p-search {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
        margin-left: 0.5em
    }

    #p-search form {
        margin: 0.5em 0 0
    }

    #simpleSearch {
        min-width: 5em;
        width: 13.2em;
        width: 20vw;
        max-width: 20em
    }

    #mw-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 10em;
        left: 0
    }

    #p-logo + .mw-portlet h3 {
        display: none
    }

    
}
```

```html
<table class="wikitable">
<tbody><tr>
<td>1) Il Corriere della Sera pubblica l'articolo che si vede nello screenshot ("A causa dei botti di capodanno sono morti in Italia almeno 400 cani e gatti").<div class="thumb tnone"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:250px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti1.png" class="image"><img alt="Botti1.png" src="/images/thumb/1/1d/Botti1.png/248px-Botti1.png" decoding="async" class="thumbimage" srcset="/images/thumb/1/1d/Botti1.png/372px-Botti1.png 1.5x, /images/1/1d/Botti1.png 2x" data-file-width="375" data-file-height="398" width="248" height="263"></a> <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti1.png" class="internal" title="Ingrandisci"></a></div></div></div></div>
</td>
<td>2) Un'influencer con 4000 follower nelle sue storie esprime la sua opinione in maniera molto energica:<blockquote><p>"TESTE DI CAZZO"</p></blockquote>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>3) Una ragazza legge la storia dell'influencer e le scrive in privato il messaggio che segue:<div class="thumb tnone"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_2.png" class="image"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/7/73/Botti_2.png/300px-Botti_2.png" decoding="async" class="thumbimage" srcset="/images/7/73/Botti_2.png 1.5x" data-file-width="362" data-file-height="465" width="300" height="385"></a> <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_2.png" class="internal" title="Ingrandisci"></a></div>Immagine 1</div></div></div>
</td>
<td>4) L'influencer, invece di rispondere in privato, pubblica una nuova storia mostrando disprezzo per l'idea della ragazza (senza farne il nome però).<div class="thumb tnone"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_3.png" class="image"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/b/bf/Botti_3.png/300px-Botti_3.png" decoding="async" class="thumbimage" srcset="/images/b/bf/Botti_3.png 1.5x" data-file-width="323" data-file-height="373" width="300" height="346"></a> <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_3.png" class="internal" title="Ingrandisci"></a></div>Immagine 2</div></div></div>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>5) La ragazza, com'è comprensibile, <b>si offende</b> e risponde a sua volta con una sua storia, taggando l'influencer:<blockquote><p>«la stupidità la colgo nella tua persona e anche la tua cattiveria perché cerchi di mettermi alla gogna pubblica. Se non sai gestire il tuo cane non sono affari miei».</p></blockquote>Si noti che la ragazza ha preso una svista, infatti l'influencer - pur usando toni molto sopra le righe - aveva censurato il suo nome, non l'aveva esposta a pubblica gogna, tuttavia ha solo 300 follower.
</td>
<td>6) L'influencer replica in così:<div class="thumb tnone"><div class="thumbinner" style="width:302px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_4.png" class="image"><img alt="" src="/images/thumb/7/72/Botti_4.png/300px-Botti_4.png" decoding="async" class="thumbimage" srcset="/images/7/72/Botti_4.png 1.5x" data-file-width="410" data-file-height="456" width="300" height="334"></a> <div class="thumbcaption"><div class="magnify"><a href="/wiki/File:Botti_4.png" class="internal" title="Ingrandisci"></a></div>Immagine 3</div></div></div>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browsers have different default values, even though most of them are same.

Designers usually tackle this problem by normalizing/reseting the default browser values using a [Normalize Script](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

You can read about this more in this [article.](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/)

Also you can use a [CSS reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) like the one from YUI.  It will make your pages more consistent across all browsers, including font rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The style is divided into 2 types:
1- default style (agent) which is the default style provided by the browser
2- modified style(developer) which is created by the developer.

This style may differs from browser to another or if the user modifies it. So, you can reset this style and when it comes to font-size you can set your font-size i the root element to 62.5% and use rem unit to deal with your values. As 62.5% acts as the default browser font-size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units